# Apache forwarding request to another server

Tags: apache, port, forward

I want apache to forward request coming to one server to another server. Here is the complete scnario:

There are 3 servers:

1. Machine A - IP: A.A.A.A - Client machine which wants to call an API there on machine C.
2. Machine B - IP: B.B.B.B - Intermediate machine
3. Machine C - IP: C.C.C.C - Machine hosting the API.

API URL: http:// Machine c:**8000**/v1/customer/....

Connectivity status:

1. Machine A -> Machine B: Telnet on port 80 - Good
2. Machine B -> Machine C: Telnet on port 8000 - Good
3. Machine A -> Machine C: Telnet on port 8000 - Bad

Ideally, from Machine A I want to call an API on machine C, but since I do not have direct n/w connectivity between A and C, I have to take this route.

So I wanted to set up apache server on machine B such that: 
From Machine A, make an API call - 
http:// **Machine B:80**/v1/customer/.... which then forwards it to Machine C on port 8000.
C serves the request and sends the response back to A.

The task might be simple but me being new to this apache, if someone can please tell me the solution, it will be great for my tomorrow's deadline :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

After some research and googling further was able to do it. Here is what I did - might be helpful to those who are facing the same problem:

In httpd.conf file of machine B added the following:

ProxyPass        /v1/customer      C.C.C.C:8000/v1/customer

ProxyPassReverse /v1/customer      C.C.C.C:8000/v1/customer

Thus from the client (machine A) if the call is made as B.B.B.B/v1/customer, then it will be 
forwarded to C.C.C.C:8000/v1/customer

mod_proxy module is required for ProxyPass.

Comment: Tick your own answer! I'm having the exact same problem with CherryPy.

Comment: This link  provides more detailed info on this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension.

Comment: Above solution worked for me after uncommenting above this line in httpd.conf "LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so"