# CherryPy forwarding request to another server

Tags: http, routes, port, cherrypy, forward

I'm having the same issue as [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10100830/apache-forwarding-request-to-another-server), but with nginx and CherryPy. I am trying to allow clients to access `192.168.0.4:80/otherpath` through GET requests made to `192.168.0.3:80/forward`, where `192.168.0.3` is a host running nginx and CherryPy. nginx should perform the redirection. Requests to all other URLs served by `192.168.0.3` should be satisfied by the local CherryPy.

I adapted a suggested nginx config by Andrew Kloos:

```
server {
  listen          80;
  server_name     192.168.0.3;
  root            /;

  location /forward {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.0.4:80/;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
  }
}
```

which performs the forwarding as required. What configuration is required to direct other requests to a local CherryPy server, and how would CherryPy need to be running to accomodate this? I think this may be verging on a ServerFault question.

Answer (score 0):

So you are serving CherryPy behind Apache?

If so, try this...

In httpd.conf file added the following:

```
<Location /appserver/>
ProxyPass 192.168.0.3:80/forward 192.168.0.4:80/otherpath
ProxyPassReverse 192.168.0.3:80/forward 192.168.0.4:80/otherpath
</Location>
```

You will also need the mod_proxy module for ProxyPass to work with Apache.

Or for nginx edit your nginx.conf file add this to your server section:

```
location http://192.168.0.3:80/forward {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.0.4:80/otherpath;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Andrew

Comment: No, just CherryPy on its own. I'll update the question. I understand that if it can't be done currently, I'll use Apache to route some requests to CherryPy and others to the second host.

Comment: I'm not aware of a simple CherryPy solution.  I'm using nginx to proxy my CherryPy app.

Comment: Something small and high-performance like nginx instead of Apache would be a much better idea. Thanks for the tip. I'll try this and report back with how it works out.

Comment: You're welcome.  ok - I've updated my answer for using nginx as a proxy.

Comment: Hiya. Sorry about the really long delay - blocking work items elsewhere in my life. :) I've updated the question with my progress so far - I looked around for example nginx configs for the problem I'm trying to solve, but I'm fairly new to web admin in general and there seems to be a variety of confusing ways to achieve what I want.