# Cross site using Angular

Tags: php, angularjs, api

I am getting data cross site from an API that requires an API key and ID.

Therefore I do not want to expose the key and ID on the client side. At some stage I will be making my own API so my app will become a bit of a mashup and I will use MYSQL to output json. So I will be using Apache.

Can and how do I use php as a local proxy to work with Angular? Will this solve my issue about my API Key being exposed?

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that the right way to do that is to sending request from client to Apache server(not directly to API).

Apache should be configured as [proxy server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) to your API. 
Id and Key of API should be added to proxied request by Apache. In that way you would never expose API Key and Id on client.

Comment: So put the ID and key as a var or parameters in the proxy script?

Comment: I've spent a few hours searching and Ben Almans is the closest I have been. I can't understand that this is the closest I have come to

Comment: I have checkout to find more information for this topic and found quite similar situation in next [stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10100830/apache-forwarding-request-to-another-server) and suggested solution with step by step [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension)